# Win 8 RECIMG fails when writing image

Tags: windows, backup, freeze, disk-image

Recimg hangs showing 1% of the image written. Creates target file on drive, lots of disc activity but doesen't write any data.  Tried with a couple of different target drives (internal and USB) from elevated CP and using RECIMG Manager. Left the process overnight - still at 1%.  This is absoulutely consistent, no error message reported.

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hang; it shows 1% for approximately 10-20 mins. After that period of time it shows the real progress.  Depending on your Windows 8 partition and backup data, it will finish within 30 minutes with ultimate compression.

Comment: except he said it ran overnight. That's a lot of 30 minutes.